# Remove 'read' button from skype for business

Tags: skype-for-business

Every time someone sends a message during a meeting using skype for business, a yellow bar pops up asking me to click 'Read' to indicate I'm caught up on all the messages. I ignore it because I think it's unhelpful but I would like for it never to display that bar again. How can I get rid of the yellow bar with the 'Read' button permanently?

Comment: You can leave feedback for Skype for Business here: https://www.skypefeedback.com/